# TransformedBitmap in WPF is producing black lines under Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, system.windows.media

When porting a WPF application from windows 7 to windows XP, I found that where I was displaying a TransformedBitmap, thin, patterned black lines appear vertically down the image on transforms that aren't power of 2 resizes (1/2, 2, 4).

This is the code used to load the image from a file ('ImageSource'), and apply the transform:

```
ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform(zoomRate, zoomRate);
ImageDisplay = new TransformedBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageSource)), transform);
```

Is there a setting or property that controls this, or is it more likely a hardware or driver issue?

Edit: This appears to be unique to TIFF images - switching to a different image format (like png) caused the image to resize without an issue.